# Exception when sorting NSMutableArray which contains all NSDate objects

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray

```
//list has type of NSMutableArray

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES] autorelease];
[list sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I got this exception:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDate 0x5d57980> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date.'

Any idea? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSDate does not have the `-date` method, so your NSSortDescriptor won't work.

Why not just use

```
[list sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

?

Comment: Thank you! Actually first I thought I needed to define the compare:, but actually compare: was defined in the system, correct?

Comment: @sza: [Yes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:).